# How do I find the second order transfer function from this response graph?

Tags: transfer-function, systemresponse

[image: Response Graph Acceleration]

I am trying to find the second order transfer function from this response graph, however since I can't find the correct overshoot value I'm stuck. The graph runs from 0 to 10 seconds and starts at 1 second. The acceleration starts at 0 and ends at 0.
The zero's are [0 -1.5+10i and -1.5-10i ] and the poles are [-1.5 -1-9i -1+9i].

Comment: What was the input waveform? I also don't see infinite overshoot either.

Comment: I have edited the post. This is all the information given.

Comment: If you know the poles and zeros you basically have your answer and the response graph is of no consequence.

Comment: I just need to know how you determine the overshoot when the final value is 0.

Comment: (1.) Are you trying to find a second order transfer function, but the order of the system is 3?
(2.) You have a zero at 0, so the step response steady state value is 0.
(3.) The acceleration starts at 0 and ends at 0 ==> I guess this is an impulse response and not a step response. Overshoot is measured for a step response
(4.) You have a 1sec delay. So the transfer function is not a rational polynomial function.

Comment: The input is indeed a step function that makes a step of 1 at 1 sec. When I got this problem they said I needed to find a second order transfer function.

Comment: @Kingkopa did you get any results on this problem? I got the same problem